# QT 5.2 has no kit or qmake with MingW after installation

Tags: qt, mingw

I downloaded the QT 5.2 build for MingW/OpenGL build and installed it. When I run QTCreator and try to create a project, I can't set it up because there is no kit available to choose from. I have MingW installed, so I tried to point QT to this installation, but there is qmake as well missing. I'm not sure if the manual configuration of the compiler would suffice to have a kit to choose from, but that would be my expectation.

So the question is, how do I setup QT properly that it recognizes my MingW installation and how do I get qmake to continue with QT? After downloading a 600MB package I would have expected that it works out of the box.

OS is Windows 7 and my MingW uses gcc 4.8 so it should be the same version that QT brings in it's package as well.

Comment: My this will help you: My Qt 5.2.1 Mingw in *Qt Versions* tab points to `C:\qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin\qmake.exe`. And then I have a kit which uses this Qt version in *Kits* tab.

Comment: You should check Options tabs *Kits*, *Qt Versions* and *Compilers*. If you can't solve this from them, maybe add screenshots of the dialogs to the question, showing as relevant details as you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I installed QT without MingW support, because I already have it installed. So this means I absolutely have to use the version provided from QT?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can configure the compiler of the MinGW version you have, and use that in the Kit. However, that MinGW then must be binary compatible with the libs you installed. There are for example some threading and C++ exception options, which must match. To be safe, *either* build Qt with the MinGW you have from sources, *or* use a known-good pre-built combination (such as both libs and gcc coming from Qt installer together).

Comment: Thanks! Currently I'm trying to build QT from source as my preferred solution. The only question left open then would be if QT desginer is included in the source pakacge, or if I can download this seperately.

Comment: If you provide this as an asnwer, I would gladly accept it, as soon as I could test it.