# Qt 5.7 with MinGW: qmake.exe missing

Tags: qt

I tried to install Qt 5.7 with MinGW on Windows 10 (32bit). In tools -> options -> build&run I see that the programm has found the MinGW debuggers (gdb.exe) and the MinGW Compilers automatically, but there is no MinGW-Qt-Version and no MinGW Kit. As I understand, one can add them, but for the Qt-Version one needs qmake.exe (MinGW -> bin...). That doesn't exist.
I also tried to install MinGW seperately, but there the qmake.exe didn't come up as well.
Copying the qmake.exe from another computer didn't help. If I use the copied version for "creating" a MinGW-Qt-Version, it says something like: "The Qt-Version isn't installed properly, please execute make install".

I've read [QT 5.2 has no kit or qmake with MingW after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604126/qt-5-2-has-no-kit-or-qmake-with-mingw-after-installation) and some other questions, but couldn't find a helpful answer.

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW says:
"Do I have to build Qt? Perhaps not. The official Qt SDK installer will work just fine. Follow these steps only if you want to learn how to make a cutom build or if you aim a x64 target. "
So it should be possible to run Qt without building, shouldn't it?

So what can I do to get qmake.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW is used to build your own Qt installation, with special parameters, usually for static linking purposes. It's not required for Qt to work.

The way to have MinGW bundled with Qt is to activate it during the installation process. They'll ask you what additional components to add, for example several MSVC versions, Qt Creator, or Qt 5.6. That doesn't change the base Qt content, if you ticked Qt 5.7 (that includes qmake.exe).

About QMake itself, check in your installation folder, inside /bin/. There's no reason for it not to be there, since it builds the .pro files, and it's included in every Qt installation. If it's not there, try reinstalling Qt, something might have done wrong during the installation.

As for compilation, use the MinGW kit provided inside Qt's settings. If you use the MSVC kit, it will obviously fail since you don't have it. But you should have a qmake.exe in /bin/ regardless of your compilator.

Comment: During the installation process I ticked MinGW (the two latest versions) and I thought that that would be enough. But in the Creater there is a MSVC-Qt-Version, that does not work, because there is noc compiler for that. That's no suprise because I don't have VC2015 installed. In /bin/, ther's no qmake. That's my problem. I'll try again tomorrow and reinstall it...

Comment: As I said, you don't need MSVC. I have Qt 5.7 on a MinGW-only machine, and it has the qmake.exe without needing MSVC. Also, only take 1 MinGW I would say, to prevent conflicts (even though Qt should handle both well). As long as you compile your sources using the MinGW Kit, it's fine. Don't use the MSVC Kit, since you don't have MSVC.

Comment: I installed it once more and now it works. Seems that I didn't understand the installation wizard.

Comment: Bugs can also happen. Glad it worked ! You could also have tried the Maintenance Tool to add the component, I forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

From here I can see only mingw530 https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.7/5.7.0/. What are the version you have? In this case, all the versions has to be same

you said: " So it should be possible to run Qt without building, shouldn't it?
"
Ans: If you are not with the same version then yes, you have to build it. Example, qt 4.8 is not available with VS 2013, in this scenario you have to build and use.

Comment: The installation wizard of Qt gives the opportunity to install MinGW together with Qt. I did that, so the versions should be compatible. I don't want to use MSVC, but the Qt Creator.